# Cannot programmatically access some files in iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

## This may be my solution

I suspect that my problem occurs because I did not turn on "iCloud" capabilities but since I have a free developer account I cannot do that.

If turning on "iCloud" capabilities is the solution, **is there also some documentation which states this**?

I only found [documentation regarding "CloudKit"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html) which never refers to "iCloud Drive".

On this [website](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/icloud-drive/) there are some links to additional documentation.

---

## Problem statement

Folder structure in iCloud Drive:

- "TestApp" (directory with the name of the app in iCloud Drive)

  - "test" (directory)

    - "testFile 1.txt" (open document using `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`)
    - "testFile 2.txt" (trying to open document programmatically)

If I open a document in a directory using `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller)) I can call `document.open(...)` without problems (`document` is a `UIDocument` subclass). However if I want to programmatically access the other file in the folder there is an error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “testFile 2.txt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/TestApp/test/testFile 2.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x2829d20a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

#### How I try to programmatically access "testFile 2.txt"

When the user opens "testFile 1.txt" I get the url of it i.e.:

```
"file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/TestApp/test/testFile%201.txt"
```

Now I'm using the following code to try to access "testFile 2.txt" (see also inline comments):

```
// I get this url from the delegate method `UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate.documentBrowser(_:didPickDocumentsAt:)`
let file1URL = // ...
let file2URL = file1URL
    .deletingLastPathComponent()
    .appendingPathComponent("testFile 2")
    .appendingPathExtension("txt")

let success = file2URL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() // returns `false`

TestDocument(fileURL: file2URL).open{ success in
    print(success) // prints `false` and see ERROR above
}

// checking existence
let fm = FileManager.default
fm.isUbiquitousItem(at: file1URL)    // returns `true`
fm.fileExists(atPath: file1URL.path) // returns `true`
fm.isUbiquitousItem(at: file2URL)    // returns `false`
fm.fileExists(atPath: file2URL.path) // returns `false`
```

As you can see "testFile 2.txt" 'does not exist' for the file manager.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an analogy:

You are a guest in someone's home.  You ask for some water.  They take a bottle from the fridge and give it to you.

Does that mean that they have given you permission to go to the fridge and take a beer or bottle of wine?  No.  Does it imply permission to search through the contents of their fridge to see what they have?  No.  Can you ask explicitly for a beer?  Yes.  Can they say "No"? Also yes.

Similarly, your app is a guest on the user's device.  It operates in a sandbox. It needs to ask for permission to access resources outside the sandbox.

In the case of file access it needs specific permission for the file it wants to access.  It can't just create a file path and access a file; The user needs to specifically grant permission to access a file.

In this case the permission is granted via the `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`.  Your app was not granted access to `testFile 2.txt` so iOS acts as if that file doesn't exist.  If you want access to that file you have to ask explicitly.

There is no capability for an app to access the complete contents of a user's files.

Comment: Thank you for this great analogy! However I thought that the app directory (here "TestApp") is also inside the sandbox!? Are then all iCloud Drive files outside of the app sandbox?

Comment: All iCloud file (and dropbox file and OneDrive files and any files provided by a file provider) are outside the sandbox.  When you use the document browser, iOS gives you permission to that file; you have to use `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` to exercise that permission.

Comment: You created the directory "TestApp" in your iCloud Drive.   You could have called the directory "Fridge" if you wanted and still access it if you were granted permission.  There is no implicit access simply because the app and the folder have the same name

Comment: Can you also write that in your answer please? I am still a bit confused: see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW13 There they only mention "iCloud Containers". Is this the same as the "TestApp" directory? If yes, then one has to activate the iCloud capability.

Comment: No, [iCloud containers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html) are a private store that an app can use to synchronise documents and key-value stores between a user's devices.  iCloud containers are visible to the application without any other permissions since they are considered the app's data. The user can't see the contents of the iCloud container using the files app and can't modify the contents directly

Comment: iCloud containers can have a Documents folder and make this folder visible to the user via the Files app.